Why Doesn't My Header Div Stay Centered When I Scroll The Image?
I am trying to center my header div. It works most of the time. However, once I make the screen window width smaller than the image and scroll the the right side of the image, the header div begins to veer off to the left. I cannot seem to fix this problem.
This is the code that I currently have and I have tried everything I could think of to center it when I scroll the image, but I just cannot.
To see what my problem is, go into full screen snippet mode and then make your window small enough, so that you have to scroll to see the rest of the image. And once you scroll enough the to the right, the header moves to the left.
I would like to keep the image to be the same width and height.


.text{
    text-align:center;
}


#header {
    position: sticky;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}


#div{
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 675px;
    width: 1350px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background:gray;
}


#image{
    position:relative;
    height:675px;
    width:1350px;
}
<div id="header">
    <h1 class="text">Title</h1>
    <h3 class="text">SubTitle</h3>
    <h2 class="text">SubTitle</h2>
</div>

<div id="div">
    <img id="image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1411569800/photo/fluttering-blank-white-flag-on-flagpole-isolated-on-black-background.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Nn74uzTU1_VWvGBdgr0Fk6Ahmqfj5ZX51WHjF1Vodts=">
</div>




You can center a div by giving it a margin:auto and a width of 50% rather than positioning it left:50%. You can see this working here on W3C Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

That's a nice thing to know if things ever go wrong with my current method. Sadly it didn't help my problem though...

The body tag renders as a block by default (HTML spec) so it's establishing a width based on its container (the window) and the grey div is overflowing out of it.  Your sticky header is behaving normally within the body tag's width.
I guess you could set the body to display:inline-block to force it to expand to contain the grey div, but I personally get nervous about mucking around with the body tags for how it might effect the layout of other elements on the page.  Would it be possible for you to wrap your content in a container?  If so, this is what I'd do:


.text {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    display: inline-block;
}

#header {
    position: sticky;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 160px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#div {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 675px;
    width: 1350px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background: gray;
}

#image {
    position: relative;
    height: 675px;
    width: 1350px;
}
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="text">Title</h1>
        <h3 class="text">SubTitle</h3>
        <h2 class="text">SubTitle</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div">
        <img id="image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1411569800/photo/fluttering-blank-white-flag-on-flagpole-isolated-on-black-background.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Nn74uzTU1_VWvGBdgr0Fk6Ahmqfj5ZX51WHjF1Vodts=">
    </div>
</div>




Could you make this is a runnable snippet? Because this still isn't fixing my problem by keeping it centered when I scroll to the right of the image.

Also, I've edited my post to use an image so you may more clearly see what I want to accomplish.

I've solved it. What I did was use your container div concept but put it solely for the div with id="div" and then added overflow:scroll; and max-width:100%; to it.

If you want header to center according to screen size then you need make parent div more flexible so that it uses 100% of available space of screen. You can achieve that with help of flexbox .
Below is simple example, similar to your snippet.


body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header{
  position: sticky;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}


#image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
<div id="header">
    <h1 class="text">Title</h1>
    <h3 class="text">SubTitle</h3>
    <h2 class="text">SubTitle</h2>
</div>

<div id="div">
    <img id="image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1411569800/photo/fluttering-blank-white-flag-on-flagpole-isolated-on-black-background.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=Nn74uzTU1_VWvGBdgr0Fk6Ahmqfj5ZX51WHjF1Vodts=">
</div>




This does work... but I would like my image to stay the same size.

I've now edited my post so you may see what I mean and want to accomplish.
